# Determining Partitioning in spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, rdd

I was going through [this](https://medium.com/dataseries/determining-number-of-partitions-in-apache-spark-part-i-e21a9ced6ad4) blog and comes under below paragraph:-

1. If the config is set to some value, and the maximum value is above the config value, then the maximum value is chosen.
2. If the config is set and the maximum value is below the config value, however, the maximum value is within a single order of magnitude of the highest number of partitions among all upstream RDDs, then the maximum value is chosen. For example, if the maximum value is 120, the highest number of partitions among upstream RDDs is 1000, and the config value for ‘spark.default.parallelism’ is 1050, then 120 is chosen.
3. If the config is set and the maximum value is below the config value, however, the maximum value is not within a single order of magnitude of the highest number of partitions among all upstream RDDs, then config value is the answer. For example, if the maximum value is 80, the highest number of partitions among upstream RDDs is 1000, and the config value for ‘spark.default.parallelism’ is 1050, then 1050 is chosen.
4. If the config is not set, then the maximum value is answer.

point 1 and 4 are clear to me but I am confused for point number 2 and 3, I am not able to understand below:-

- what is the meaning of --> "the maximum value is within a single order of magnitude of the highest number of partitions among all upstream RDDs"
- from where the number 1000 has been driven.
- If I am joining two RDDs i.e A and B where A has 30 partitions and B has 120 partitions then what is the meaning of maximum in point 2 and 3? is it reflects 120 here?

can someone please help me understanding the same with some example.

Comment: why do you need to use RDD API?

Comment: Hey, I don't need it but need to understand the logic, after all underneath everything is RDD and sometime it helps you to optimize things while writing the code.